# broadcasting webcam with jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

What I want is broadcasting webcam with audio to X people on a webpage . I am familiar with jsf , I am using primefaces utilities and apache tomcat 7 for servlet container. Where should I start ? Is there any way embedding the vlc player webcam recording to my webpage or some different recorders for example realplayer etc.. Or should I follow very different way ? Thanks for advice.

Comment: I understand you want to broadcast the **live** webcam video? It's **your** webcam, or the viewers' webcam?

Comment: my webcam , or somebodies' webcam ,  who wants to broadcast anyting s/he use her/his webcam and others watch them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that MyFaces, PrimeFaces and IceFaces all have video player components which could be used for displaying videos saved on your server, but there are obviously quite a few nuts and bolts to get out of the way before you are live streaming video from one user and broadcasting the live feed to others right in the browser.

You have intrigued me as I never get to do anything this fun in my work with JSFs, and I will most definitely be following this and linking anything else I find.

My first suggestion for discovering/inventing the answer yourself would be to implement some chat functionality first.  Create a jsf page with a session scoped backing bean and have it publish a message to a JMS topic.  Have another jsf page which is backed by a session scoped bean which subscribes to that same topic.  At some point you will need to refresh the subscribers page without the user making a request, or in other words you will need to push those messages to the browser.  The component suit you use may have ways of taking care of this wiring for you without you having to write the Ajax yourself.

Ted Goddard, at Primefaces demonstrates 'Cloud Push, or ICEPush' with a slide show about 35 minutes into this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30bk95Ac7QE).

Obviously at some point the really hard part comes where you have to stream video from the browser to a session managed bean and then broadcast that to the JMS topic.  For this I might suggest looking into using an applet in your JSF page.  That way you have a way of clearly accessing the remote users system using java.  In the applet you could stream the webcam feed to the same JMS queue, or use some other form of streaming video back to your webserver so that you could push that stream to each 'observing' user.

Comment: Thanks for you advice , as you said primefaces has video player components bun not  for live webcam streaming..I thought doing it using applets but it is not what i want.

Comment: @mft : Have found a solution for this yet?